# What are the steps necessary to solve this Calculus problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

$$(1-xy^3)dx=x^2y^2dy$$

I'm thinking carrying the $dx$ over to the other side, and $x^2y^2$ to the other so we'd get

$\dfrac{1-xy^3}{x^2y^2}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$. Then I think you find $\dfrac{u}{du}$ which is $u= 1-xy^3$ and $Du=3y^2$ and put $\dfrac{1}{3}$ outside, then integrate.

I have no clue what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

your differential equation $$x^2y^2\, dy + (xy^3-1)\, dx = 0 $$ is almost an exact differential.it can be made into an exact differential if we multiply by the integrating factor $x$ to get $$ x^3y^2\, dy + (x^2y^3-x)\, dx = 0$$ and the solution is $$\frac13 x^3y^3 - \frac12x^2 = constant. $$

$\bf edit:$ here is the reason why $$ M \,dx +N\, dy =   (x^2y^3-x)\, dx + x^3y^2\, dy = 0$$ is an exact differential. the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial M}{\partial x} = 3x^2y^2, \frac{\partial N}{\partial y}= 3x^2y^2 $$
therefore there is a function $F$ such that $$dF = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx +\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} dy = (x^2y^3-x)\, dx + x^3y^2\, dy$$  that is

$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = (x^2y^3-x), \frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = x^3y^2 $$ from these it follows that $$F = \frac13 x^3y^3 - \frac12x^2. $$

Comment: You have to be careful here also to check for the trivial solutions.   In this case,  $x=0$ gives us $-dx=0$,  so $x=c$...which includes $x=0$ as a possibility, so the vertical line $x=0$ is a solution  (Not a function, but hey)

Comment: Why is x^3y^2dy+(x^2y^3−x)dx=0 = 1/3x^3y^3−1/2x^2=constant.

Comment: @Alan, i did not see that possibility.

Comment: @stan, please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

here is another way to solve this. break up the differential equations 
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1-xy^3}{x^2y^2} $ into two 
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = \frac 1{3y^2},\quad \frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{3(1-xy^3)}{x^2}.$$

the first one gives you $$y^3 = t+C  \tag 1$$ and the second one can be turned into 
$$ \frac{dt}{dx}= -\frac{3t}x + \frac{3}{x^2} - \frac{3C}x \tag 2$$
the solution to the homogeneous problem is 
$$t = \frac B{x^3},\quad \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac1{x^3}\frac{dB}{dx} -3\frac{B}{x^4} $$ putting this back in $(2),$ we have
$$ \frac{dB}{dx} = 3x - 3Cx^2 \to B = \frac{3x^2}{2} - Cx^3 + D, t = \frac{3}{2x} -C+\frac D{x^3} \tag 3$$  eliminating $t$ between $(1)$ and $(3)$ gives $$y^3 = \frac{3}{2x} + \frac D{x^3} \text{ or } \quad \frac{1}{3} x^3y^3 - \frac 12x^2 = constant $$